# HTML5 Canvas 35x35 pixelpaint

Tags: html, canvas

I want a 35 x 35 pixel painting program on my website..
I have used different things, but it doesnt work for me.

The script must have only black OR a color picker should be nice..
And a vertical and horizontal pixel width/height of 35 pixels.

If you can help me you are my hero

Regards
Pascal

Comment: You ask us to design & code a painting app for you ... that's way too broad to ask us for! You should try coding it yourself. **Hint:** Create a canvas that has width=350 & height=350 (that's canvas element size -- don't size with css!). Use `context.scale(10,10)` to enlarge the painting area to a size the user can see well. Listen for click events and paint the clicked pixel with `context.fillRect(mouseX,mouseY,1,1)`. When done, create a second canvas that is 35x35px. Draw the larger canvas content onto the smaller canvas with `context.drawImage(largerCanvas, 0,0,350,350, 0,0,35,35)`

Comment: Thanks for helping me, i've no experience with canvas. I will try your suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now.. I cant fisish it, the click pixels will not place at the right place.. They overlapping each other. The pixel field must be 35x35 and not 350x350

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);
function onload(){
   var canvas = document.getElementById("badge");
   c = canvas.getContext("2d");
   c.scale(10,10);
}

function getPosition(event)
{

  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("badge");

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  c.fillStyle = "red";
  c.fillRect(x / 10, y / 10, 1, 1);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "x:" + x + " y:" + y;


}
```

```css
#badge {
background-image: url(http://www.sivd.nl/canvas/bg.png);
cursor: crosshair;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload()">
<center>
<br><br><h1>Badge editor</h1><br>
<p id="demo">Klik op onderstaande veld om je badge te maken!</p><br>
<canvas id="badge" onclick="getPosition(event)" width="350" height="350">
Download Chrome om canvas te gebruiken..
</canvas>
<br>
<button>Potlood</button>
<button>Kleurenkiezer</button>
<button>Gum</button>
<br>
</center>
</body>
```